# Strapi - /admin folder not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-management-system, strapi, pm2

So i got an issue while deploying it on the server.

Localhost works fine, however when I open the strapi admin panel on the server, it asks for admin folder which I could not find. Here is the working link to checkout: https://s-dash.ihoops.uz

So i have searched how to skip this error, as the error asks for /admin/runtime~main and /admin/main js files

So, I am building the strapi admin panel with **yarn build** command, but it is working fine in localhost as I have mentioned earlier. So after building the strapi, in my project folder shows up a folder which's name is **build** but after I put it to server **public_html,** the error reveals like it cannot find the find the folder **admin**. After that, I renamed my **build** folder to admin to check can it handle the error after all because the <runtime~main> and <main> javascript files are inside of build folder.

After I renamed the folder to admin the strapi admin panel launched but the error type is changed:

Then now, it is asking for /admin/init and /admin/project-type. After I linked process manager to admin panel (**pm2**) it still stood like this in pending.

/server.js file:

```
const strapi = require('@strapi/strapi')
strapi().start()
```

/ecosystem.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'app',
      script: 'yarn',
      args: 'start-production',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production'
      }
    },
  ],
};
```

/package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi",
    "start-production": "env NODE_ENV=production yarn start",
    "production": "env NODE_ENV=production yarn build"
},
```

So, I think would be in the hosting in the /config/server.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env("HOST", "0.0.0.0"),
  port: env.int("PORT", 1337),
  url: env('PUBLIC_URL', 'https://s-dash.ihoops.uz'),
  app: {
    keys: env.array("APP_KEYS"),
  },
  webhooks: {
    populateRelations: env.bool("WEBHOOKS_POPULATE_RELATIONS", false),
  },
});
```

But when I changed the host url from 0.0.0.0 to my hosting url, localhost stopped working also, but after that i found out the url should exist in the path file so, I added the PUBLIC_URL, however, now localhost except public host also

Comment: So after sometime I decided to do the work till the end, so when you are deploying, you need some free ports to deploy!